# Steps are not displayed inside Allure report using mocha-allure-reporter and Cypress

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, cypress, allure

I tried the following code in spec.js in Cypress expecting to have steps displayed in the allure report.

```
 describe("simple test demo", () => {
    it("simple passed test", () => {
      cy.task('allureTestStep')
    });
  })
```

Inside index.js under plugins folder in Cypress, allureTestStep is defined as follows:

```
 require('mocha-allure-reporter');
 module.exports = (on) => {
   on('task', {
      allureTestStep () {
         const testStep = allure.createStep("initial", () => {
            var a = 1 + 2;
            console.log("Value "+a);
         });
         testStep();
         return null
      }
    }
 }
```

Console log is displayed in the command window. 
Test suite and Test case with name and title labels along with their values are displayed in the xml file under allure-results directory as expected. However test step related information is not displayed.

Any inputs are highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I am wondering if you need to return something from the step functions. Ref [Allure API](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_runtime_api), "allure.createStep(name, stepFn) – define step function. Result of each call of this function will be recorded into report."

Comment: @HiramK.Hackenbacker I tried returning "Value "+a inside the createStep but didn't help. Also tried `return testStep()` instead of `return null` inside `allureTestStep()`, it didn't work either

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I suspect that by doing `require('mocha-allure-reporter')` you are instanciating the allure reporter module "inside" cypress execution environment... which is different (and has been spawned) from mocha environment where allure plugin actually runs.  If that makes any sense.